# Right click, text selection and window drag stops working

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). Since yesterday I have been unable to drag windows, select text, or use the right corner click to open the context menu using the built in trackpad. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Can you test with an external trackpad or mouse?

Comment: External mouse works

Comment: What is connected to the computer?  Can you test with everything unplugged? (power, usb, monitors, etc.)  This article may be a help: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203146.

Comment: I dont think its that problem, cause the trackpad is responsive, only the clicking does not work anymore.